# Managing Gemfile.lock with gems bundled from same repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

Here's the situation. I work on a large Rails 3.2.13 app (Ruby 1.9.3, Bundler 1.3.5). We've recently begun the process of making this app less monolithic by breaking some components out into gems/engines. However, we have kept the source code in the same git repository. So we've got a file structure like:

```
APPNAME
|-app
|-gems
|---engine1
|---engine2
|-lib
```

etc.

Then the Gemfile looks like:

```
gem 'engine1', :path => File.expand_path('../gems/engine1', __FILE__)
gem 'engine2', :path => File.expand_path('../gems/engine1', __FILE__)
```

So far so good. My problem is that `Gemfile.lock` is no longer consistent between developers. Whenever I fetch changes from source control and run `rspec` or `rails server` or whatever, I get a modified `Gemfile.lock` where the diff looks like:

```
 PATH
-  remote: /Users/OTHER_DEVELOPER/PATH_TO_APP_SOURCE/gems/engine1
+  remote: /Users/ME/APPNAME/gems/engine1
```

We've always followed what we considered to be the best practice of checking our `Gemfile.lock` into source control, but now that's causing git headaches. Has anyone dealt with this problem before? Any ideas for a solution?

Comment: Although it is a good-practice, if it doesn't work for you, you can always choose to ignore the `.lock` file from git.

Comment: FWIW, you _are_ developing a gem when you started refactoring the app into engines :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're using gems in an unintended way. They are gems, not DLLs.

If you want a gem approach, host them on a private server and refer to that server in your GEMFILE.

If you want a DLL-like approach in ruby, just use a folder for each library.

Comment: I understand this is not intended. But we don't presently see any advantages in packaging the gems in separate repositories. We were trying that for a while with one of them, but that creates its own headaches with version bumping whenever you make a change.

And we're going for more than code organization here. We want to be able to conditionally load some engines and not others on some servers. +1 but not accepting this answer (though there may be no better one).

Comment: The version bumping reluctance is further argument to say you don't need gems. You just want the `require` mechanism. Maybe you could just load the folder containing a library whenever appropriate.